# Vdeo-Call-App Fatal Error

Tags: php, ratchet, videochat

I want to use Video-Call-App made by amirsanni.

[Video-Call-App](https://github.com/amirsanni/Video-Call-App)

in local server using  wampserver it was great but i can't run it on server and i get this Fatal error :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught React\Socket\ConnectionException: Could not bind to 
tcp://0.0.0.0:8080: Address already in use in 
/srv/disk16/2535675/www/arash.mygamesonline.org/video-call-
app/ws/vendor/react/socket/src/Server.php:35 Stack trace: #0 
/srv/disk16/2535675/www/arash.mygamesonline.org/video-call-
app/ws/vendor/cboden/ratchet/src/Ratchet/App.php(80): React\Socket\Server-
>listen(8080, '0.0.0.0') #1 
/srv/disk16/2535675/www/arash.mygamesonline.org/video-call-
app/ws/bin/server.php(18): Ratchet\App->__construct('http://arash.my...', 
8080, '0.0.0.0') #2 {main} thrown in 
/srv/disk16/2535675/www/arash.mygamesonline.org/video-call-
app/ws/vendor/react/socket/src/Server.php on line 35
```

may help me run this app on server ? i'm new to this field please say me any thing that you think may i didn't do to run app.